# Is there any Dynamic Binary Instrumentation frameworks for Windows exposing an Intermediate Representation?

Tags: windows, dynamic-analysis

There are some excellent DBI frameworks for Windows (Intel PIN, DynamoRIO...) but unfortunately none of them expose an IR afaik.
I am looking for something like Valgrind's VEX that works on Windows.

Any pointers / references would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are searching for lifting assembly to IR,
look at either [BAP](http://bap.ece.cmu.edu) or [RevGen](https://dslabgit.epfl.ch/git/s2e/s2e.git).

Edit 2018: There is also great [McSema](https://github.com/trailofbits/mcsema) (supports x86, x64 and aarch64).

Comment: This may be what I was looking for. I always avoided BAP since it is written in OCAML but I guess I'll have to check it out nevertheless.

Comment: On a closer look, it does not seem that BAP supports Windows. Any experiences with compiling this on a Windows OS?

Comment: Nevermind, it accepts PE files as input. Suboptimal for my purposes but it'd make do. Sorry for the little self-chat here.

Answer (score 3):

dynamoRIO does expose an IR (see [documentation](http://dynamorio.org/docs/dr__ir__instr_8h.html)).
There is just no "written textual" form of it, it is basically a 1:1 mapping of the underlying assembly language and thus very close to the underlying architecture.

Answer (score 1):

[Intel's Pin](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pintool/) is probably what you want.

[Microsoft's Vulcan](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69850/tr-2001-50.pdf) is great, but I don't think it was ever released publicly, at least not in a standalone form.

Comment: Intel Pin would be my DBI framework of choice but I could not find any reference to an IR similar to VEX.